# Is there a method for searching for TreeNode.Text field in TreeView.Nodes collection?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, treenode

Like this:

```
TreeNode[] treeNodes = treeView.Nodes.Find(searchString, true);
```

but I want it to search in the `text` field instead of the `name` field.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I am not aware of any inbuilt method but you may use LINQ

```
TreeNode[] treeNodes = treeView.Nodes
                                    .Cast<TreeNode>()
                                    .Where(r => r.Text == "yourText")
                                    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Is this more effective(faster) than a *for* loop? Can it be done without using "Cast"? And, another thing, this does not work for children in the tree. Only for the root elements.

Comment: The fact that the question asks for a Find with the "search children" set to true, but in the *text* field instead of the *name* may explain the, rather austere, downvote.

Comment: Since I use the treeview to display data from a class, I prefer checking the class for this kind of information(which is flat) rather than the tree(which contains lots of branches).

Comment: @ThunderGr, faster than *for* loop ? I can't say, since LINQ internally uses looping. Even if there is a difference it would be negligible. And yes it doesn't search recursively, [L.B's Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12388467/961113) has a recursive solution.

Comment: This method will not search child nodes

Comment: How I Populate the treeview with the TreeNode Object ?

Answer (score 29):

To search all tree nodes (not only the direct child nodes) you can use  the extension method below

```
var nodes = treeView1.FlattenTree()
                     .Where(n => n.Text == "sometext")
                     .ToList();
```

--

```
public static class SOExtension
{
    public static IEnumerable<TreeNode> FlattenTree(this TreeView tv)
    {
        return FlattenTree(tv.Nodes);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TreeNode> FlattenTree(this TreeNodeCollection coll)
    {
        return coll.Cast<TreeNode>()
                    .Concat(coll.Cast<TreeNode>()
                                .SelectMany(x => FlattenTree(x.Nodes)));
    }
}
```

Comment: `var nodes` is a set of nodes with `.Text == "sometext"`, how can I include in this set other parents nodes, whose child already in this set, so in the end I will be able to build a tree ?

Comment: it help me to filter select node based on search text           
`treeview.SelectedNode = treeAccount.FlattenTree().Where(p => p.Text.StartsWith(txtSearch.Text.Trim())).FirstOrDefault();`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly (you last question was very confusing), you can write a find method yourself as follows

```
public static TreeNode[] Find(this TreeNode motherNode, string findNodeText)
{
    List<TreeNode> nodeList = new List<TreeNode>();
    foreach (TreeNode childNode in motherNode.Nodes)
        if (childNode.Text.Equals(findNodeText, StringComparison.CurrentCulture))
            nodeList.Add(childNode);
    return nodeList.ToArray<TreeNode>();
}
```

This method can be used like

```
TreeView myTreeView = new TreeView();
foreach (TreeNode node in myTreeView.Nodes)
{
    TreeNode[] childNodes = node.Find("Text");
    // Do something...
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The following code only shows the nodes which matches the search criteria.

Copy the following code in the search event

```
   private void tbxSearch_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            trvMenu.BeginUpdate();
            if (tbxSearch.Text.Length > 0)
            {
                for (int i = trvMenu.Nodes.Count;  i > 0  ; i--)
                {
                    NodeFiltering(trvMenu.Nodes[i - 1], tbxSearch.Text);
                }
            }
            trvMenu.EndUpdate();
        }
```

Then create the serch & filter function

```
    private bool NodeFiltering(TreeNode Nodo,string Texto)
    {
        bool resultado = false;

        if (Nodo.Nodes.Count == 0)
        {
            if (Nodo.Text.ToUpper().Contains(Texto.ToUpper()))
            {
                resultado = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Nodo.Remove();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = Nodo.Nodes.Count; i > 0; i--)
            {
                if (NodeFiltering(Nodo.Nodes[i - 1], Texto))
                    resultado = true;
            }

            if (!resultado)
                Nodo.Remove();
        }

        return resultado;
    }
```

This code is pretty nice for creating Treeview menus with many levels.