# Treeview.Nodes.Cast Not working

Tags: c#, treeview

```
TreeNode tnKey = 
    treeViewFilters
    .Nodes
    .Cast<TreeNode>()
    .Where(r => r.Text == FilterName)
    .ToArray()[0];
```

The above code is not working. It reports an error

```
Error   1   Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.TreeNodeCollection' to 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection'   

Error   2   'System.Windows.Forms.TreeNodeCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Cast' and the best extension method overload 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollectionExtensions.Cast<TResult>(System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection)' has some invalid arguments
```

I have taken code from [Is there a method for searching for TreeNode.Text field in TreeView.Nodes collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12388249/is-there-a-method-for-searching-for-treenode-text-field-in-treeview-nodes-collec) Any ideas?

Comment: This works fine in linqpad for me (replacing `treeViewFilters` with `new TreeView()`) and `ToArray()[0]` with `FirstOrDefault()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry my mistake, i forget to add 'system.linq' name space

Comment: Mark this answer of yours as answer.