# Can't set TreeView.SelectedNode Property

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I'm trying to set the selected node after cleaning and refilling my treeview. Here's the code I tried:

```
private TreeNode selectednode;
private void ElementTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)//saves changes to the XElements displayed in the textboxes
{
    BusinessLayer.ElementName = (sender as TextBox).Tag.ToString();
    string Type = (sender as TextBox).Name;
    string Value = (sender as TextBox).Text;

    if (TView_.SelectedNode!=null)
    {
       selectednode = TView_.SelectedNode; 
    }
    string NodePath = TView_.SelectedNode.FullPath.Replace("\\", "/");

    Telementchange.Stop();
    Telementchange.Interval = 2000;
    Telementchange.Tick += (object _sender, EventArgs _e) => {
        if (Type=="Value")
        {
            BusinessLayer.ChangeElementValue(NodePath,Value);//nembiztos hogy így kéne ezt meghívni
        }
        else
        {

            BusinessLayer.ChangeElementName(NodePath, Value);
            BusinessLayer.ElementName = Value;
        }            
        FillTree(BusinessLayer.Doc);
        TView_.SelectedNode = selectednode; //nemműködikezaszar!!!!!
        TView_.Select();
        Telementchange.Stop(); 
    };
    Telementchange.Start();   
}
```

For some season after I set the `TView_.SelectedNode` property it is null.
Thank you for helping!

Comment: Why are you sure there is a selected node?

Comment: Yes, but for some reason the Handle and FullPath property threw an exception while viewing in the debugger.

Comment: Yes, but i had to make a workaround. (Sorry for not writing about the solution, but i sort of forgot about that i asked it here.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't solve my problem by setting the SelectedNode property so i made a workaround.

```
 private void RefreshTreeView()
        {

            FillTree(BusinessLayer.Doc);
            TView_.SelectedNode = _selectednode;
            ExpandToPath(TView_.TopNode, _selectedPath);                    
        }

        void ExpandToPath(TreeNode relativeRoot, string path)
        {
            char delimiter = '\\';
            List<string> elements = path.Split(delimiter).ToList();
            elements.RemoveAt(0);
            relativeRoot.Expand();
            if (elements.Count == 0)
            {
                TView_.SelectedNode = relativeRoot;
                return;
            }
            foreach (TreeNode node in relativeRoot.Nodes)
            {
                if (node.Text == elements[0])
                {
                    ExpandToPath(node, string.Join(delimiter.ToString(),elements));
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code you show you seem to do this:

- store the currently selected `Node` in a variable
- clean and refill the `TreeView`
- select the stored `Node`

This is bound to fail as at the moment after the filling, the stored `Node` is no longer part of the `TreeView`'s node collection unless you have added it again in the fill routine..

I don't think you do that.

If you want to re-select some node you will need to identify it in the new collection of nodes. If the `Text` is good enough for that do a recursive `TreeView` search like the one in L.B's answer here in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12388249/is-there-a-method-for-searching-for-treenode-text-field-in-treeview-nodes-collec) (Not the accepted answer, though!)