# Why does the object is null if adding a child node?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

I m trying to add a child node but it says the object is not set.

```
public void Test(TreeView tree)
{
    tree.Nodes.AddRange(new TreeNode[] { new TreeNode("ok"), new TreeNode("test")});
    foreach (TreeNode node in tree.Nodes)
        tree.Nodes["test"].Nodes.Add("a child node");
}

private void Button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Test(treeView1);
}
```

**Edit**:
I cant answer my own post because someone marked it but the problem is that I dont set the property `Name` in TreeNode

the worked version is that:

```
public void Test(TreeView tree)
{
    tree.Nodes.AddRange(new TreeNode[] { new TreeNode("ok") { Name = "ok" }, new TreeNode("test") { Name = "test" } });
    foreach (TreeNode node in tree.Nodes)
        tree.Nodes["test"].Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("a child node"));
}
```

thanxs to [reza-aghaei](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3110834/reza-aghaei)

Comment: Where is the code that initializes treeView1?

Comment: Where is the code that creates the `"test"` node?  You have `tree.Nodes["test"]` but aren't creating that node anywhere that I can see.

Comment: @TerryTyson It just the control that added in design time

Comment: @Amy it has been created with `tree.Nodes.AddRange`

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: @Amy `tree.Nodes["test"].Nodes.Add("a child node");`

Comment: @leylafanji Okay, then, does `tree.Nodes["test"]` evaluate to null as I suspected?

Comment: @Amy right but the node is created. with the key `"test"`

Comment: `Node.Text` is different from `Node.Text`. `new TreeNode("test")` creates a node having `Text = "test"`, but `tree["test"]` is trying to find a node having `Name = "test"`.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Ahh and how I can add now the child node?

Comment: You can assign `Name` property of node as well. `new TreeNode("test"){Name = "test"}`.

Comment: You are using a `foreach`. Did you mean `node.Nodes.Add("a child node");`?

Comment: @Ondrej Tucny why you marked it as duplicate this has nothing to do with my question?

Comment: @leylafanji check this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12388249/is-there-a-method-for-searching-for-treenode-text-field-in-treeview-nodes-collec) it could be helpful

Comment: I reopened the post as it's not a duplicate of the linked post. OP knows what is the null reference exception, but doesn't know what's wrong with tree node and why it cannot be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you're trying to access a node by it's string key (which maps to the `Name` property), but you're never setting the `Name` (only the `Text`).

Try this instead:

```
tree.Nodes.AddRange(new[]
    {
        new TreeNode("ok") {Name = "ok"},
        new TreeNode("test") {Name = "test"}
    });
```

Comment: Yes, @Reza Aghaei said that too thanxs